# what's the syntax error in this simple login mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

[this php query for login why it show me the syntax error like this"( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql_quey' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp64\www\aps_db\Login.php on line 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWm49.png)" any one tel me plz

[image]

Comment: Show a part of your code.

Comment: try php code checker

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `;` on line number 4. You missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a semi colon `;` after following line.

```
$user_pass = "ali";
```

> **mysql_*** extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Missing `;` in 4 number line.Add `;`something like:

```
 $user_pass = "ali";
```

instead of:

```
$user_pass = "ali"
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add ; so it will be show error like this. 
add ";" on line 4